# Html use file from user and set as background?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, camera, background-image

I have this code for choosing a file in HTML, and I want to allow the user to choose a file, and then be able to set it as the background. Heres the code for choosing the file

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<br>
   <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="sendFile();" />
</form>
```

Or is there a way I could access the camera of the user in HTML? Basically, I want the user to be able to choose an image or take an image, and then set the image as the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can take advantage the browser's [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read files and use the file on client side
Below is a typical example of using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) for your use case:

```js
function sendFile() {
  // IN YOUR ACTUAL CODE REPLACE DEMODIV WITH
  // document.body or the body of your html
  const demoDiv = document.querySelector('#demo');
  const file = document.querySelector('#file1').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // setting image file convert to base64 string as demoDiv's background
    demoDiv.style.backgroundImage = `url(${reader.result})`;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```css
#demo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
 }
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<br>
   <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="sendFile();" />
</form>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Reference: [reader.readFileAsDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)